# SQL Query: Product name and quantity offered in each city

Tags: sql-server

I need this to return a total quantity offered for each product in each city, but I'm missing something:

```
SELECT Tb_Supplier.City, 
       Tb_Product.Name, 
       SUM(Tb_Offers.Quantity) "Quantity Offered"
FROM Tb_Supplier, Tb_Product, Tb_Offers
WHERE Tb_Supplier.Supp_ID = Tb_Offers.Supp_ID AND
      Tb_Offers.Prod_ID = Tb_Product.Prod_ID
GROUP BY Tb_Supplier.City, Tb_Product.Name, Tb_Offers.Quantity
ORDER BY Tb_Supplier.City, Tb_Product.Name;
```

The results are coming out like this:

```
Name        Name City           Quantity Sold
Bernstein   TV   Chicago            720
Bernstein   TV  Chicago         3600
Bernstein   TV  Chicago         7200
Bernstein   TV  Cleveland       7200
Bernstein   TV  Lansing         10800
Bernstein   TV  Lansing         75600
Bernstein   TV  Lansing         108000
Bernstein   TV  Madison         10800
Bernstein   TV  Madison         36000
Bernstein   TV  Stevens Point   1080
Bernstein   TV  Stevens Point   7200
Bernstein   TV  Stevens Point   12600
Bernstein   TV  Wausau          14400
Bernstein   TV  Wausau          36000
Herman      TV  Lansing         144000
Herman      TV  Stevens Point   72000
Joel        TV  Lansing         216000
Joel        TV  Stevens Point   72000
Wolf        TV  Stevens Point   72000
```

I think I need to use DISTINCT.  Would someone be able to help me with this, please?

Comment: Why are you grouping by `Tb_Offers.Quantity` when that is also inside your `SUM`?

Comment: Also, it's time to start using ANSI-92 JOINs, they've been around for almost 30 years! https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Honestly, I am really, really new at SQL, so I'm thinking this is probably just my error.

Comment: Thank you, Larnu.  Problem solved.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove:

```
Tb_Offers.Quantity
```

from grouping.
This is what you need to group:

```
GROUP BY Tb_Supplier.City, Tb_Product.Name
```

Then you aggregate for `Tb_Offers.Quantity`.